# Merge relationship does not always work (delay)

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher, graph-theory, graph-databases

In my project, I am trying to create a relationship between the labels `Subjects` and `Attributes`.

I set their corresponding *relationship* as follows:

```
MATCH (a:Attribute { aid: {params}.aid } ) 
WITH a 
MATCH (s:Subject { sid: {params}.sid } )
WITH a, s
MERGE (s)-[w:WEIGHTED {wid: {params}.wid }]->(a)
SET w = {params}
```

The **problem** is however, that after I execute this, not all relationships are formed. Moreover, in my case, there should be 52 relationship, but initially I only get somewhere arround 39 (it varies) accross. When I call the function again, then all the 52 relationships are settled.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Some **background** info:

- Prior to setting the relationships, I do create the nodes Subjects and Attributes first. However, I only proceed with creating the actual relationships after my neo4j server has resolved (using promises) with this task. I.e. Subjects and Attributes should be already filled in the database.
- I use GrapheneDB to host my neo4j server.
- The reason I am separating the tasks, thus first create labels and then the relationships is because I have multiple dynamic parameters (id's).

But perhaps there is a delay before I can make the query to create the relationship?

Or is there something else?

How can I solve this?

HELP!

---

**Promises**

Very generaly spoken, this is how I apply the promises, for `Queries` an array with the cypher scripts (they are correct) and `Params` with the corresponding parameters.

**query 1: subjects**

```
 function querySubjects() {
            var QueriesAll  = []; // array of strings
            var ParamsAll   = []; // array of objects

            for (var i=0; i<sidArray.length; i++) {

                // [subjects]
                var sid         = sidArray[i];
                var sparams     = {};
                sparams['sid']  = sid;

                // merge subjects
                var queryStr = " \
                MERGE (s:Subject { sid: {sparams}.sid } ) \
                SET s = {sparams} \
                ";

                // [+]
                QueriesAll.push(queryStr);
                ParamsAll.push({
                    sparams: sparams
                });

            } // end s++

            // --> loop queries
            loopQueries(QueriesAll, ParamsAll).then(
                function(success){
                    // -->
                    queryAttributes();
                },
                function(error){
                    // ...
                }
            );
   }
```

**query 2: attributes**

```
function queryAttributes() {

        var QueriesAll  = []; // array of strings
        var ParamsAll   = []; // array of objects

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------
        // init attributes
        var aidArray    = [];

        for (var i=0; i<sidArray.length; i++) {

            var sid             = sidArray[i];   // array of keys
            var attributes      = subjects[sid]; // object of attributes
            var attributesArray = Object.keys(attributes);

            for (var j=0; j<attributesArray.length; j++) {
                var aid = attributesArray[j];
                aidArray.push(aid);
            } // end a++

        } // end s++

        // filter out duplicates (works fine)
        aidArray        = aidArray.filter(onlyUnique);

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------
        // create queries

        for (var j=0; j<aidArray.length; j++) {

            // [attributes]
            var aparams             = {};
            aparams['aid']          = aidArray[j];

            // merge attribute
            var queryStr = " \
            MERGE (a:Attribute { aid: {aparams}.aid } ) \
            SET a = {aparams} \
            ";

            // [+]
            QueriesAll.push(queryStr);  
            ParamsAll.push({
                aparams: aparams
            });

        } // end a++


        // --> loop queries
        loopQueries(QueriesAll, ParamsAll).then(
            function(success){
                // -->
                queryWeights();
            },
            function(error){
                // ...
            }
        );
 }
```

**query 3: weights (problem happens here)**

```
 function queryWeights() {

        var QueriesAll  = []; // array of strings
        var ParamsAll   = []; // array of objects

        for (var i=0; i<sidArray.length; i++) {

            // [subjects]
            var sid         = sidArray[i];
            var sparams     = {};
            sparams['sid']  = sid;

            // [attributes]
            var attributes          = subjects[sid];
            var attributesArray     = Object.keys(attributes);

            for (var j=0; j<attributesArray.length; j++) {

                // ...
                var aid                         = attributesArray[j];
                var aweight                     = attributes[aid];

                var aparams                     = {};
                var wparams                     = {};

                // [weights]
                aparams['aid']          = aid;
                wparams['wid']          = sid + '-' + aid;
                wparams['aweight']      = aweight;

                // merge relationship subject-->attribute
                var queryStr = " \
                  MATCH (a:Attribute{ aid: {aparams}.aid } ) \
                  WITH a \
                  MATCH (s:Subject { sid: {sparams}.sid } ) \
                  WITH a, s \
                  MERGE (s)-[w:WEIGHTED {wid: {wparams}.wid }]->(a) \
                  SET w = {wparams} \
                  RETURN a,s \
                  ";


                // [+]
                QueriesAll.push(queryStr);  
                ParamsAll.push({
                    sparams: sparams,
                    aparams: aparams,
                    wparams: wparams
                });


            } // end a++
        } // end s++


        // --> loop queries
        loopQueries(QueriesAll, ParamsAll).then(
            function(success){
                // <--
                console.log('success')
            },
            function(error){
                // ...
            }
        );

    }
```

where

```
function loopQueries(Queries, Params) {
    var promises = {};
    for (var i=0; i<Queries.length; i++) {

        var queryStr = Queries[i];
        var params   = Params[i];

        var promise = queryNeo(queryStr, params);
        promises[i] = promise;//promise;
    };
    return Q.all(promises);
}

function queryNeo(queryStr, params) {
    var qq = Q.defer();
    db.cypher({
        query: queryStr,
        params: params,
    }, function (error, results) {
        if (error) { 
            qq.reject(error)
        } else {
            qq.resolve(results)
        }
    });
    return qq.promise;
}
```

---

**Delay test**

I performed a test an waited a couple of seconds before I create the relationships. And indeed, it immediately works when I include a delay. I don't understand however why my query returns that it is done, while it is not the case. How can this latency issue be solved, such that I know that it is REALLY done?

Comment: Are you sure the promise returns when the transaction is done? not just the statement, make sure to finish the tx. best is if you share your code.

Comment: @MichaelHunger I have shared the script.

Comment: Show the code that calls `loopQueries`, and the code that creates the relationships. That is, show the entire logic flow.

Comment: @cybersam Added the logic!

Comment: @MichaelHunger Added the logic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will solve your issue, but your code is unnecessarily complex. At the very least, simplifying it should make it easier to understand and debug.

There is no need to create arrays containing identical Cypher query strings, and therefore no need to use `Q.all()`. You can use `UNWIND` to tweak each Cypher query so that a single query invocation would process every passed-in `paramsAll` item, one at a time.

I have not tested the following modified version of your code, but it should at least give you an idea of how to simplify things. The `loopQueries` function is no longer needed.

```
function querySubjects() {
  var query = " \
      UNWIND {sparams} AS param 
      MERGE (s:Subject { sid: param.sid } ) \
      SET s = param \
      ";

  var paramsAll   = []; // array of objects

  for (var i=0; i<sidArray.length; i++) {

      // [subjects]
      var sid         = sidArray[i];
      var sparams     = {};
      sparams['sid']  = sid;

      paramsAll.push({
          sparams: sparams
      });

  } // end s++

  // --> loop queries
  queryNeo(query, paramsAll).then(
      function(success){
          // -->
          queryAttributes();
      },
      function(error){
          // ...
      }
  );
}


function queryAttributes() {
  var query = " \
      UNWIND {aparams} AS param 
      MERGE (a:Attribute { aid: param.aid } ) \
      SET a = param \
      ";

  var paramsAll   = []; // array of objects

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------
  // init attributes
  var aidArray    = [];

  for (var i=0; i<sidArray.length; i++) {

      var sid             = sidArray[i];   // array of keys
      var attributes      = subjects[sid]; // object of attributes
      var attributesArray = Object.keys(attributes);

      for (var j=0; j<attributesArray.length; j++) {
          var aid = attributesArray[j];
          aidArray.push(aid);
      } // end a++

  } // end s++

  // filter out duplicates (works fine)
  aidArray        = aidArray.filter(onlyUnique);

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------
  // create queries

  for (var j=0; j<aidArray.length; j++) {

      // [attributes]
      var aparams             = {};
      aparams['aid']          = aidArray[j];

      paramsAll.push({
          aparams: aparams
      });

  } // end a++


  // --> loop queries
  queryNeo(query, paramsAll).then(
      function(success){
          // -->
          queryWeights();
      },
      function(error){
          // ...
      }
  );
}

function queryWeights() {

  var query = " \
      UNWIND {params} AS param 
      MATCH (a:Attribute{ aid: param.aid } ) \
      MATCH (s:Subject { sid: param.sid } ) \
      MERGE (s)-[w:WEIGHTED {wid: param.wparams.wid }]->(a) \
      SET w = param.wparams \
      RETURN a,s \
      ";

  var paramsAll   = []; // array of objects

  for (var i=0; i<sidArray.length; i++) {

      // [subjects]
      var sid         = sidArray[i];

      // [attributes]
      var attributes          = subjects[sid];
      var attributesArray     = Object.keys(attributes);

      for (var j=0; j<attributesArray.length; j++) {

          // ...
          var aid                         = attributesArray[j];
          var aweight                     = attributes[aid];

          var wparams                     = {};

          // [weights]
          wparams['wid']          = sid + '-' + aid;
          wparams['aweight']      = aweight;

          paramsAll.push({
              sid: sid
              aid: aid,
              wparams: wparams
          });

      } // end a++
  } // end s++


  // --> loop queries
  queryNeo(query, paramsAll).then(
      function(success){
          // <--
          console.log('success')
      },
      function(error){
          // ...
      }
  );

}
```

Comment: Wow, the UNWIND is pretty much what I was looking for. I'll try again and see if it works (my feeling is that it will since we deduct this whole thing to 3 queries)

Comment: It worked! Make sure to use `param` and not `{param}`, struggled a bit with that.